# Preventing an ul element with the class 'sub-menu' from being child element of a list item in a Wordpress menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I've got a menu that is generated using the wordpress template tag `<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>`.

The generated code is:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">Current Page</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-58">Menu Item #1
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li class="page_item page-item-62">Child Item #1</li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-60">Child Item #2</li>
        </ul><!--END page-item-58 -->
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My question is: how do you prevent `<ul class='sub-menu'>` from become a child of `<li class="page_item page-item-58">`?

I would like the generated code to look like this:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">Current Page</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-58">Menu Item #1</li><!--END page-item-58 -->
    <ul class='sub-menu'>
        <li class="page_item page-item-62">Child Item #1</li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-60">Child Item #2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

I can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something you should be trying to achieve. It is illegal for the ul element to be a child of another ul element : http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element

See also the w3 spec : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2

Comment: Ahh thanks, I didn't know that it was illegal for the ul element to be a child of another ul element. If theoretically all the ul and li elements were divs, how could the problem be solved?

Comment: You're then looking at the implementation of wp_nav_menu. I'm not sure whether you can constrain it like this, but surely the documentation would help you extend the default behaviour? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

So I saw that you wanted that structure, but with div's instead of ul's and li's. Can you try the code found [here](http://pastebin.com/8NBqruT7) and see if that works for you?

It's a class that extends `Walker_Nav_Menu` and the output of it is:

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <div id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
        <div id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4"><a href="#">Sample Page</a></div>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <div id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5"><a href="#">Sub-menu</a>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                    <div id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6"><a href="#">Sub-sub-menu</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-7"><a href="#">Another sub-menu</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What it will do is, that it will not wrap first-level sub-menus in their belonging parent, but will do so for the deeper sub-menus.
Here is the structure of the menu:

```
 - Sample Page
   - Sub-menu
     - Sub-sub-menu
   - Another sub-menu
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're after, but probably you can play around with the walker and see if you can achieve what you want.